# Big O how to calculate the n

Tags: math, big-o

I am having some problem understanding this solution.

`10n^2 + 4n + 2 ≤ 11n^2` for all `n ≥ 5`,

I could solve this in another way e.g. `10n^2 + 4n + 2 ≤ 16n^2` for all `n ≥ 1`

But how do we get the `n ≥ 5` for the first solution?

Comment: What? Where does Big-O come into this? How are the two equations related?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [math.se].

Comment: @Dukeling, BigO is in Computer Science too and its used to analyse algorithms.

Comment: Yes, but in this particular case, you're just trying to prove `10n^2 + 4n + 2 ≤ 11n^2 for all n ≥ 5`, which doesn't have much to do with big-O, or Computer Science in general (and, by the way, questions about [cs.se] are typically better suited on [cs.se] - [so] is more for when you have a problem with actual code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true by inspection that the inequality doesn't hold for n less than 5.

```
In [5]: for n in range(1, 6):
   ...:    print 10 * n**2 + 4 * n + 2 <= 11 * n**2
   ...:     
False
False
False
False
True
```

It makes sense to inspect for small values. Otherwise you can [use a little calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273055/how-can-i-tell-if-one-polynomial-is-greater-than-another-over-an-interval) or [plot the two functions to see where they intersect](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e8uv1sthn27).

Comment: So basically I must have to inspect it to find that n.

Comment: It makes sense to inspect for small values. Otherwise you can [use a little calculus](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273055/how-can-i-tell-if-one-polynomial-is-greater-than-another-over-an-interval) or [plot the two functions to see where they intersect](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e8uv1sthn27).

Comment: @usmcs Should include that comment in the answer and its pretty much complete.

Answer (score 3):

Simply because `4n + 2 ≤ n^2` for `n` greater or equal 5. It is true for `n=5`. If `n` increases by 1, the left side increases by 4, while the right side increase by a value greater than 5, because `(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1`. So the statement remains true for larger values of `n`. You can easily check that it is not true for smaller values.

Comment: And `4n + 2 ≤ n^2` is equivalent to `6 ≤ (n-2)^2`, which obviously is satisfied the moment `3 ≤ n-2` or `5 ≤ n`. No induction necessary, just a quadratic inequality.

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to show this.